# Object detection in images (HOG)

Tags: python, image, scikit-learn, object-detection, scikit-image

I want to detect objects inside cells of microscopy images. I have a lot of annotated images (app. 50.000 images with an object and 500.000 without an object).

So far I tried to extract features using HOG and classifying using logistic regression and LinearSVC. I have tried several parameters for HOG or color spaces (RGB, HSV, LAB) but I don't see a big difference, the predication rate is about 70 %.

I have several questions. How many images should I use to train the descriptor? How many images should I use to test the prediction?

I have tried with about 1000 images for training,  which gives me 55 % positive and 5000, which gives me about 72 % positive. However, it also depends a lot on the test set, sometimes a test set can reach 80-90 % positive detected images.

Here are two examples containing an object and two images without an object:

[image: object 01]

[image: object 02]

[image: cell 01]

[image: cell 02]

Another problem is, sometimes the images contain several objects:

[image: objects]

Should I try to increase the examples of the learning set? How should I choose the images for the training set, just random? What else could I try?

Any help would be very appreciated, I just started to discover machine learning. I am using Python (scikit-image & scikit-learn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're in the right path, but let me raise some considerations:

1 - The number of the training set would be always important in classification
problems (usually, more is better). However, you must have good annotations
and your method should be robust to outliers.

2 - From the images that you put, it seems that the color histogram would
be more discriminative than HOG. When using color histograms I usually go
for Lab color space with correlated a-b histograms. L is luminance and
is very dependent on image acquisition (e.g. brightness). One method
that is used to re-identify pedestrian is to divide the images into
blocks and compute the histograms inside these blocks. This can
be helpful.

3 - The best way to test your classification method is cross-validation:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29#k-fold_cross-validation

4 - Did you try other classifiers? Weka could be very interesting to
easily tests different methods/parameters:
http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/

5 - Finally, if you still have bad results and have no idea of which
kind of features you should be using, you can apply deep neural networks
to it!

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions, they are very helpful! I quickly tried LAB histograms (also suggested from scikit-image mailing list) and it looks like with the lightness channel I get very good results for detecting cells with an object correctly. However it predicts very bad for cells without an object. On the other hand, to detect cells without an object, HOG performed very well. I think with combining both models it might work (I am not sure whether this would be ok). I still did not cross validate, so it's all preliminary. Thank you for this hint!

Comment: Often there are other objects around the cell which are dark stained but they should be not detected. I think that's why I am getting lots of false positives when using LAB histogram but with not with HOG.

Comment: I have one more question, it look like that the bin size plays a big role. How do I choose the right bin size? Are there any rules or rather like "try and error"?

Comment: Hey @honeymoon, I would like to inquire about how you handled the annotated images in case they had bounding boxes. e.g how to assign labels to specific parts of the image if you have their x y, width and height.